# Does the Loremaster Applicable Knowledge Secret ignore feat prerequisites?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

The loremaster prestige class gets to choose a [secret](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/loremaster/#TOC-Secret) on certain level ups. The 8th secret is "Applicable knowledge        Any one feat."

Do I have to meet the prerequisites of this feat, or is it really ANY feat? Could I get [major spell expertise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/major-spell-expertise) despite the fact that my mid-level character cannot cast 9th level spells?

I have googled for errata and come up empty. Most [class features](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/#TOC-Bonus-Feat) that give a bonus feat specify whether you must meet the prerequisites. The description is three words long.

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77186/8610), but not necessarily *answered* definitively. *This* is, however, an ancient beef, dating back to 2000 and that divides player and DM, optimizer and casual player, father and son, and man and dog. *Beware the worm can's opening!*

Comment: Was just checking it out, he is talking about cases where the class ability says *gain x feat* as bonus feat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must meet the requirements of the feat. Like every other class ability that grants feats. According to the [PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html):

> Some feats have prerequisites. Your character must have the indicated ability score, class feature, feat, skill, base attack bonus, or other quality designated **in order to select or use that feat**.

The bolded part is a *blanket* rule that applies to all feats in the game, like those gained by a [fighter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/#TOC-Bonus-Feats), *unless said otherwise*, like on the [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/#TOC-Bonus-Feat) and [ranger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/#TOC-Combat-Style-Feat-Ex-) classes:

> A monk need not have any of the **prerequisites normally required** for these feats to select them.
>
> even if he does not have the **normal prerequisites**.

Or when a class or ability grants you a feat as a **bonus feat**, the requirements are not required, as per [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77200/21153), unless the ability says the requiements must be met.

You could argue that this ability is considered a bonus feat, but the *rules-as-written* here says it is not. And thus, [that quote from James Jacobs](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=369?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#18422) does not apply here.

Keep in mind that granting *any* feat in the game is really strong, way stronger than any of the other secrets available, as you could even get feats designed for monsters or mythic heroes if the requirements are ignored completely. Classes that grant **bonus feats** that ignore the requirements either specify the feat gained, or have a list of available feats (like all *combat feats* or *style feats*).

Comment: What is the source of the first block quote? Core rulebook?

Comment: Its actually from the SRD, but i will replace from a source from the PRD.

Comment: Your last passage needs elaboration.  It's not immediately clear why this bonus extra feat isn't a 'bonus feat' (not that you're necessarily wrong about that).

Comment: The comparison used to be with the [loremaster's secret applicable knowledge](http://dndsrd.net/loremaster.html#_top) and the [rogue special ability feat](http://dndsrd.net/rogue.html#rogue-special-abilities) (both *3.5e* links). *Pathfinder* fixed the latter with the rogue advanced talent [feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-advanced-talents/feat) but left alone the former. *Sigh.*